# Write a code with collection library in python

Tags: python

I have a list in which there are several characters, for example, the characters of the first word have the same letters as the characters of the third word, but their order has changed. I want to write a code that uses the collection library to create a main list at the output and the number of words  The ones that are the same in this main list should be made and there are the same words in them

Input list example:

```
['abc','acb','hds','sdh','nm','mn']
```

Output example:

```
[[abc,acb],[hds,sdh],[nm,mn]]
```

No matter how hard I tried, I could not complete it

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried so far ? To check if two strings have the same characters you can use `sorted(str1) == sorted(str2)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ['abc', 'acb', 'hds', 'sdh', 'nm', 'mn']


def match(lst: list[str]) -> list[list[str]]:
    new_lst = []
    for i in range(0, len(lst)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(lst)):
            if sorted(lst[i]) == sorted(lst[j]):
                create_new_pair = True
                # check if it already has a pair to join
                for pair in new_lst:
                    if lst[j] in pair:
                        create_new_pair = False
                        break
                    elif sorted(pair[0]) == sorted(lst[j]):
                        pair.append(lst[j])
                        create_new_pair = False
                        break
                # create new pair if it is a new one
                if create_new_pair:
                    new_lst.append([lst[i], lst[j]])

    return new_lst


new_lst = match(lst)
print(new_lst)
```

Comment: Thanks.Can you write it with collection library for me?

Comment: I don't really know this library. what do you need from this library?

Comment: I am not very familiar with it myself, but I have to write this code using this library